# Conditional ControlTemplate based on property of ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

Is it possible to "select" a different control template based on a property of a viewmodel?

I have the following user control template:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">

        <RadioButton 
            GroupName="DisplayButtons" 
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Based on a boolean in the viewmodel, I want to use either a `RadioButton` or a `Button`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use different views for each case but this method is more useful in the case of complicated templates.
For the current case, the easiest way is to use Triggers:

**Method 1**

```
﻿<UserControl x:Class="Myusercontrolnamespace.Views.Myusercontrol" 
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:mc = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   xmlns:d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" "  
   mc:Ignorable = "d" Height="auto" Width="auto" >

    <UserControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioButtontTemplate">
        <RadioButton/>
      </DataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
     <Button/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

   <Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
      <ContentControl.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RadioButtontTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRadioButton}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
     </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Method 2**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Myusercontrolnamespace.Views.Myusercontrol" 
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:mc = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   xmlns:d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" "  
   mc:Ignorable = "d" Height="auto" Width="auto" >

    <UserControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioButtontTemplate">
        <RadioButton/>
      </DataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
     <Button/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

 <Grid>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="globalControlTemplate">
     <ContentControl Content="{Binding }">
         <ContentControl.Style>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                 <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RadioButtontTemplate}" />
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConsumerType}" Value="Business">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
         </ContentControl.Style>
     </ContentControl>
   </DataTemplate> 

   <ContentControl Content="{Binding globalControlTemplate}" />
 </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Cordially

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that sets the `Template` property:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
                        <Button Content="Button" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
                                <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
</UserControl>
```